# substring removal in find -exec

Tags: bash, find

When using

```
$ find . -name string~ -exec cp {} FOO \;
```

is there a way to use `{}` in `FOO` to remove the tilde character as we usually do with bash substrings

e.g. :

```
 $ echo ${string%substring}
```

I aim to copy the files named string~ to string (the opposite of `$ find . -name string -exec cp {} {}~ \;`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a case where you should stuff the code execution into a spawned shell.

```
find . -name '*~' -exec sh -c 'cp "$0" "${0%~}"' {} \;
```

This way you don't need to write a script.  You just do it in a one-liner.

---

Note: You don't need the `--` "end of options" specifier for `cp` here, because `find` will prefix the files found with `./`, which will prevent them from being parsed as options to `cp`.

(The exception to this `./` prefix is if the current directory `.` is itself "found," but of course that name doesn't end with a tilde, nor could it be mistaken as an option flag.)

---

I would even use a spawned shell for appending a tilde to the copy's name; in other words I'd use:

```
find . -name string -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" "$1"~' find-sh {} \;
```

in preference to:

```
find . -name string -exec cp {} {}~ \;  # Don't use this!
```

as the latter is unspecified by POSIX and therefore unportable.

From the [POSIX specifications for `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

> If a *utility_name* or *argument* string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether *find* replaces those two characters or uses the string without change.
>
> ...  If more than one argument containing the two characters "{}" is present, the behavior is unspecified.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, aha, yes, I see—treatment of `--` as an options terminator is [guideline 10](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02).  Fixed answer.